# String array or new class?

Tags: android, arrays, string, class

How my application works is once a user opens it, it will open to a screen where it will find out depending on the button the user clicks, how many holes of golf they want to play (18 or 9.)  From there it will launch the main activity where, depending on what the user chose, will depend on the rules of the application.  ie - If they choose 18, the save button wont activate until the 18th hole, same for 9, it will activate on the 9th hole.  This will also trigger a final score notification, etc.

Im curious if I should create a separate class for 9 holes and 18 holes, or if I should just pass some sort of value from the open screen, to the main activity that sets the values at 9 or 18?

I guess I am curious on this programming etiquette as I am not very familiar with the best practice of something like this.

Entry screen will look something like this as of now (I have not finished 9 hole button or help button but will be the same as 18 unless launching a seperate class)

```
case R.id.button18Holes:

        //*********************************//
        //***LAUNCHES ACTUAL APPLICATION***//
        //*********************************//
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(src.getContext(), EasyPar.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

        Intent iStartValues = new Intent(this, EasyPar.class);
        String[] startValues = new String[] {"18"};
        iStartValues.putExtra("strings", startValues);
        startActivity(iStartValues);

        break;

    case R.id.button9Holes:
        break;

    case R.id.buttonHelp:
        break;
    }
```

Im not sure if that string array is the proper way to pass one to another activity either?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't feel this is worth writing a full answer, but let's say you create it with a separate Activity for 9 and 18 hole games.  Would these two classes share common items like a menu?  Links to other activities?  If so, I'd think about extending the Application class to store application-wide variables such as the number of holes being played.  Then just write one Activity that switches in the necessary places to tailor it to the user's game.

Comment: Thank you!  I am currently working on building a globalvariables class that extends application!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pure OO people would say you should create an abstract base class containing common operations and fields, and then for the specialisations, create sub classes.  Case statements and if statements like you have above are not pure OO.

Same goes for arrays in general - in pure OO you might have them as a field in a class, but any operations performed on them would be inside a class.

Personally, I would say go with whatever you think will be easier to maintain, quicker to program and more obvious to other people reading the code.  I guess that doesn't really answer the question though :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely not be using an array for only two objects! That is overkill. This is important because you have very little memory to work with on a mobile device and arrays eat up some memory. Also you should be using button listeners instead of switch/case statements to find what is going on.

First, I would highly suggest diving into OOP and learning the fundamentals of program using Java before diving right into Android. You do not have to go this route though, but I will say that if you choose to not learn the basics and fundamentals... prepare for a long hard road.

With that said, the simplest way to do this in Android IMHO is like this... The comments should provide you with enough insight to what is going on.

The Class files:

GolfTestActivity.class

```
package com.jmarstudios.golf;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class GolfTestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // This is the main xml layout: res/layout/main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // Get a handle to the two buttons in main.xml
        final Button _nineHoles = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final Button _eighteenHoles = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button2);

        // Create a listener for button1
        _nineHoles.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Start the nine hole activity
                GolfTestActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent().setClassName("com.jmarstudios.golf", "com.jmarstudios.golf.NineHoleActivity"));
            }
        });

        // Create a listener for button2
        _eighteenHoles.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Start the eighteen hole activity
                GolfTestActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent().setClassName("com.jmarstudios.golf", "com.jmarstudios.golf.EighteenHoleActivity"));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

NineHoleActivity.class

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.jmarstudios.golf;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

/**
 * @author DDoSAttack
 *
 */
public class NineHoleActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // We simply inflate the layout: res/layout/nineholeslayout.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.nineholeslayout);
    }
}
```

EighteenHoleActivity.class

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.jmarstudios.golf;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

/**
 * @author DDoSAttack
 *
 */
public class EighteenHoleActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // We simply inflate the layout: res/layout/eighteenholeslayout.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.eighteenholeslayout);
    }
}
```

and in the XML files...

res/layout/main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Do you want 9 holes or 18 holes?" />
    <Button 
        android:text="Nine Holes" 
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button 
        android:text="Eighteen Holes" 
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

res/layout/nineholeslayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Nine Holes"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

res/layout/eighteenholeslayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Eighteen Holes"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Finally you need to add the activities to your AndroidManifest.xml file

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.jmarstudios.golf"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".GolfTestActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".NineHoleActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".EighteenHoleActivity"></activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Here are some handy references that I HIGHLY recommend:**

http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html

Hope all that helps as this is pretty much a simple copy/paste thing